# Where are all my files on eclipse? They were on the left side of the page?

Tags: eclipse, file, ide

On eclipse ide i had a file system on my left. Now its just not there. How do i get it back like i dont want the folders i want the files in the folder (The whole eclipse directory set-up) thanks so much!

Comment: I suspect you're looking for "Package Explorer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your perspective is set correctly (i.e. the Java perspective which you can set on the top right) and it is still not showing the default view, go to Window ---> Reset Perspective.

Or, you can use the key combo `Alt+Shift+Q,P` or Window ---> Show View ---> Package Explorer. Both these show the package explorer.

Comment: Gee thanks Cameron Just got it! and thank you emil for the effort ! :D

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window > Show view and see if you can find the one you're looking for.

Comment: OK but what is it called? the thing im looking for?

Comment: Probably something including "explorer", "navigator" or something like it. There are a few of those and your description is a bit vague.

Comment: By default, you might be in the "Java Perspective".  From there, you can "window, Show View" 1) Navigator, 2) Project Explorer and/or 3) Package Explorer.  From any of these panes, you can click the left arrow to "drill down" for more detail.